# How to handle multiple inputs in a function without defined input type

Tags: python

Suppose I have a function without defined input type

```
def func()
```

And I have multiple inputs with different types

```
False
31, 57, 78
```

How do I acuire those inputs?

Do I use

```
input = raw_input()
```

to acuire all inputs together

or should I defined an empty list and put inputs into this list

```
input_list = [int(i) for i in input('').split()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you're reading input from a file (using input redirection), you can use `STDIN` module available in `sys` package. The snippet follows:

```
import sys

all_inputs = list(map(str, sys.stdin.read().split()))
print(all_inputs)
```

Note that all of the inputs are read as strings. You can later iterate over those inputs and do whatever you want.

- If you're providing the input through a console (terminal or some other prompt), then you might want to use the following snippet.

```
inputs = []

while True:
    try:
        line = list(map(str, input().split()))
        inputs.extend(line)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    
print(inputs)
```

Note that you've to press `ctrl + c` (in Linux) key combination to stop reading the input from the console.